# How do I customize the view element for the application.hbs template?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In an app generated by ember-cli, the html generated by application.hbs is wrapped in a view:

```
<body class="ember-application">
  <div id="ember284" class="ember-view">
  </div>
</body>
```

If I create a component, I have a component-name.js file where I can specify options to modify the component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'nav',
  classNames: ['main-menu'],
  layout: layout
});
```

How do I modify the attributes of the element that is wrapping the application.hbs template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a file in the `app/views` directory that follows the [naming conventions](http://www.ember-cli.com/#naming-conventions), `application.js`

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ['my-app-view']
  // this is the application view
});
```

Now confirm it works by inspecting your html:

```
<body class="ember-application">
  <div id="ember287" class="ember-view my-app-view">
    <h2 id="title">Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Ember.View` direct access is deprecated starting from version `2.x`. What they did, is they have converted the `Ember.View` to an abstract class. Now you should use `Ember.Component`. As the short-cut, you could try something like this:

```
// app/views/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['customClassName']
});
```