# EmberJS 1.13 / No more view / Customize application.hbs element / Dont want additional div of ember-view

Tags: templates, ember.js, view

Ember automatically puts whatever you have in application.hbs inside a `<div class='ember-view'>`.

For example, if your application.hbs is:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  ...
</div>
```

The resulting DOM in the browser will be:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='ember345' class='ember-view'>
      <div class='wrapper'>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

That gives me a problem because the 3rd CSS I'm using depends on certain structure. To make it work, it has to be like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I need to tell ember ****not**** to wrap the content of application.hbs inside that `<div id='ember345' class='ember-view'>`. How to do that?

Before 1.13 you can make a view (following the naming convention), explained here: [How do I customize the view element for the application.hbs template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177037/how-do-i-customize-the-view-element-for-the-application-hbs-template)

But now I'm using 1.13..., and there's no longer the notion of "View"..., and I don't want to use ember-legacy-view add-on (sounds like a step back to me).

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks,
Raka

Answer (score 1):

Oh... just figured out, you can still create a corresponding view in ember 1.13 (without having to use legacy-view).

I simply did (in ember-cli)

```
ember g view application
```

And edit the generated views/application.js to be like this (specify empty string as tagName):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: ''
```

});

Comment: A better solution is needed since this causes a deprecation warning and will not work after v2.0.